# Android: Accessing directory path using URL

Tags: android, url

I have a directory of files that I want to access from a server but in my codes I have no particular files that I would want to refer, just wanting to get the parent directory folder name.

for example: www.website.com/path

I've tried using URL("file", "website.com", "path") to retrieve the directory but it seems like it is not working and there are no MalformedURLException thrown as well.

Can I access the folder this way? or is there another way to go about it?

Comment: I don't have any examples on hand but you could search for android and ftp or android httpget/httpput/httppost etc. But it would be much easier to help you if you could give some additional details on what you want to do...

Comment: ok I actually wanted to access a dictionary folder (WordNet) containing various files in it. The initialization is done something like this: **IDictionary dict = new Dictionary(url); dict.open();** So the url is actually pointing to the dictionary folder name rather than a specific file. Then after the initialization only will it access the  files inside for other functions. Hope u get what I mean.